# Where should exceptions live in a maven project directory?

Tags: java, exception, maven, project-management

Is there a specific location within the maven project structure, or package naming convention when defining your own exceptions for a project? I assume throwing them into an 'exceptions' package will be fine, but I thought I'd ask here since the googlebox wasn't yielding any answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What Tomasz said, but if there are a lot of Exceptions, put them in their own package - typically called `com.mycompany.<topic>.exceptions`

Answer (score 7):

This question has nothing to do with maven. Basically you are asking where in package hierarchy should exceptions be placed.

Since exceptions are like any other class, advices are the same: close to where they are used (preferably the same package).

Answer (score 0):

No. Maven is unaware of how Java packages are organized.